# Modificar el tamaño de una imagen ( CGSizeMake )

Tags: swift2

Estoy realizando un código a través del cual cambio de lugar una imagen y a la vez se modifica el tamaño de la misma utilizando `CGSizeMake`, pero no logro modificar las dimensiones solo desplazarlo,

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagen: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func animar(sender: AnyObject) {

        var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(self.imagen.frame.midX, self.imagen.frame.midY))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(160, 200))
        animation.duration = 3.0

        **var resizeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bound.size")
        resizeAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CGSize: self.imagen.bounds.size)
        resizeAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(200, 50))
        resizeAnimation.duration = 3.0**

        imagen.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
        imagen.layer.addAnimation(resizeAnimation, forKey: "bound.size")    
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

no encuentro el error,

gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Te has olvidado una `s` en `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bound.size")`
Es decir, lo correcto es:

```
CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size")
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! ese efectivamente ese fue el error, lo pase por alto.

Comment: Hola +Luis. ¿No deberías también acepar la la respuesta  como correcta? saludos